# Return Multiple Error Messages to an XHR Request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, http

I'm doing some login/auth stuff, and I want to flash error messages when the user inputs improper data. Here is my code for getting a list of errors that happen when a user tries to register:

```
flash[:error] = []
resource.errors.each do |error|
  flash[:error].push error
end
```

and, as an after_filter in ApplicationController, I set the HTTP to the flash error array:

```
response.headers['X-Flash-Error'] = flash[:error] unless flash[:error].blank?
```

Because I'm using AJAX and I'm not using a .js.erb file to deal with the AJAX callback (business constraints), I can't use the typical flash object that is passed to the template.

When I try to access the error in my javascript ajax callback using `xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Flash-Error')`, I get a string of the errors separated by commas. Obviously I can split these items on the comma and get an array easily enough, but is there a way to simply pass an array in the header from the server?